# Android Master/Detail prevent reload view

Tags: android, tablet, master-detail

I'm coding an android app, only for tablets, and i'm using the master/details template..

everytime I tap an item in the left side of the app (master), the right side (detail) load a different view. I want a behavior similar to iOS tab, for example:

I tap in the item 1, the right side load the view A.
I tap the item 2, the right side load the view B.

but if I tap again the item 1, I want to show me again the view A, but without reload/regenerate the view, just show me the view again, in the same state as before.

Hope you understand me, sorry for my bad english.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that makes sense, except this is android. You can make a memory leak monster if your really really want to.. Why are you fighting how android works? iOs works like that, but it's a completely different system with no commonalities under the hood.

you can retain an instance, and manually swap fragments with the fragment manager. Or you can keep the data in a headless fragment.

Just reload the fragment, go with the flow, don't make a buggy application :)

Now if you are asking how you can retain a state, that's a different question.. now your talking backstacks...